# Sass: @use makes error, undefined variable

Tags: css, sass, dart-sass

I'm using Sass and want to use `@use` keyword instead of `@import`. Because, `@import` has many buggy problems. Also only dart-sass supports this feature, I changed node-sass into dart-sass. However, problem is occurred.

My original code

```css
@import '@carbon/colors/scss/colors'
```

dart-sass and `@use` applied code

```css
@use '@carbon/colors/scss/colors'
```

**Error: Undefined variable.**

How can I solve it?

Comment: according https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use you have to use `_colors.scss`(also try without `.scss`)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem might be that `@use` adds a namespace to your variables – in order to continue using variables like you did before (as `color: $variable` instead of `color: namespace.$variable`) you need to import it like so:

```css
@use '@carbon/colors/scss/colors' as *;
```

according to the [official docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use).

Comment: This solution is not working for me. Is there any issue with using `@use` within a file to `@use` another file?

Comment: check you are calling the correct relative path; `@use "../abstracts/variables" as *;` and add use to each file that requires external values like mixins or variables too

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! The documentation sucks for Dart.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that @use is file scoped, so you need to call it in each file you need it.

Also if you put * (@use 'variables' as *)  you don't have to put a namespace.