# @use not working in Sass to import variables but @import is working

Tags: css, sass, colors

I have a sass variable declared in the file _variables.scss. When I import that file using @use, I get an error when compiling stating "Error: undefined variable". If however, I use @import instead, everything compiles just fine.

Here's the first file which is imported

```
//_variables.scss
$primaryColor: rgba(199, 26, 113, 0.747);
```

And here's the file which is doing the importing.

```
//styles.scss
@use 'variables';

header {
background: $primaryColor;
}
```

When compiling this returns "Error: undefined variable". But if I change @use to @import, it works just fine.

Why does @import work but @use does not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sass: @use makes error, undefined variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62127255/sass-use-makes-error-undefined-variable)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Variables imported with `@use` [have a namespace](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#loading-members). Therefore, you need to prefix your variable name with the namespace (i.e. instead of `$primaryColor`, write `variables.$primaryColor`):

```scss
@use 'variables';
// @use './variables' // creates the same namespace

header {
  background: variables.$primaryColor;
}
```

You can also [rename the namespace](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#choosing-a-namespace):

```scss
@use 'variables' as 'renamedVariables';

header {
  background: renamedVariables.$primaryColor;
}
```

If you don't want to use the namespace, you can [load variables without it](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#choosing-a-namespace):

```scss
@use 'variables' as *;

header {
  background: $primaryColor;
}
```

But imo namespaces make your stylesheet neater (e.g. it's clear where each variable comes from, and you won't accidentally overwrite one variable with another), so i'd stick with them...

*[Another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63012314/4551707) pointed me in the right direction*

Answer (score 0):

using the underscore _ in sass simply means you are declaring a partial When Sass sees these files, it will not process them into CSS files.

By default a partial requires that it should be imported into another file that will inevitability be processed into CSS in order for it to be output. rather than use the @use

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case because the example on the Sass website uses "use" and has an underscore on the file being used without using import. https://sass-lang.com/guide  Also, "use" will work on files with underscores - I've tried importing styles (i.e. not variables) using "use" and an underscored file and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have a directory in my SASS folder that is named "abstracts". Inside that folder I make an index.scss file. Inside that index file I have the following

```
@forward "config";
@forward "variables";
@forward "named-colors";
@forward "hsl";
@forward "maps";
@forward "mixins";
@forward "reasonable-colors";
```

Each of those files is a partial "_variables"
In the rest of my Sass files that I want to use all those variables and mixins in, I put this at the top

```
@use '../abstracts' as *
```

That way all the variables are there to use. Of course your folder structure may be different. After the abstract folders I have folders for Basic files, Layout, modules,pages and themes. Each file in each of those folders uses @use '../abstracts' as *