# In SCSS webpack, I can't get variables to work

Tags: import, sass, electron

This is my webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './renderer.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

And this is an example of my scss workflow:

```
--variables.scss--
$mainColor: #000;

--colors.scss--
p {color: $mainColor;}

--style.scss--
@use './partials/variables';
@use './partials/colors';
```

In my renderer.js file im importing the styles like:

```
import "./assets/css/style.scss";
```

And the styles is basically working fine, though the variables give compile error like:

```
undefined variable, color: $mainColor;
```

I have tried added style,css and sass loader to the module rules, but still doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sass: @use makes error, undefined variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62127255/sass-use-makes-error-undefined-variable)